# Changing API Versioning Strategy

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, api-versioning

I'm working on an API, using [django rest framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) which is currently in production. The versioning strategy in use is [namespace versioning](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/versioning/#namespaceversioning). I would like to switch to [acceptheader versioning](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/versioning/#acceptheaderversioning) as it seems to suit the project better.

Is there a way to make the change smoothly without breaking previous API versions.

Comment: Why not move to a different endpoint and start from there

Comment: like, create a new endpoint for a new API version? That is what I am doing now something like, /api/v1.0.0/ and /api/v1.2.0/

Answer (score 1):

Versioning is very simple.

Create folder in your app and name it to `v1`

Like this image:

[image]

yourApp > urls.py should be like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('v1/', include('api.v1.urls')),
]
```

Then create `urls.py` in v1 folder, it should something like this:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from api.v1.classes.Plan import listPlan
from api.v1.classes.preInvoce import preInvoce    

urlpatterns = [
    path('plan/list', listPlan.as_view(), name="listPlans"),
    path('plan/buy', preInvoce.as_view(), name="preInvoice"),
]
```

If you want have version 2 you need to create new folder called v2 and have urls.py in it.

and your app urls.py should be like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('v1/', include('api.v1.urls')),
    path('v2/', include('api.v2.urls')),
]
```

Put your own and new urls in v2/urls.py

Your final v1 urls like this:

```
localhost:8000/v1/planList
```

Your final v2 urls like this:

```
localhost:8000/v2/newUrlInV2
```

Both v1 and v2 urls should works correctly.

Comment: How does this address the question, which is " I would like to switch to acceptheader versioning " ?